# Alternative to LDA

Tags: classification

Is there an alternative to using LDA and regression models to classify data where the response variable is assumed to have a linear relationship with the predictor? Essentially I am trying to find boundaries where the predictors change from one class to another. In the example below with 3 classes

```
c1 = {1,2,3,4,5,10,11}
c2 = {2,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}
c3 = {9,11,13,14,15,16,17}
```

5 and 12 will be the boundaries as they correctly classify majority of the predictors in each class. I am writing my own function which will give me flexibility to specify the cost. It will help if there is something more efficient/flexible already.

Comment: [linear svm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Linear_SVM)

Comment: Thank you @user603. I was shying from using the SVM but it works neatly.