# SVM with overlapping classes

Tags: classification, svm

Following my earlier [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62318/alternative-to-lda?noredirect=1#comment119547_62318), I have successfully run linear svm on some datasets, however for other datasets, it is failing. These are the datasets where range of one class lies within that of the next class. What I did not mention in my post was that my classes have to be ordered i.e c1 should precede c2 which should precede c3. So for example linear SVM is not very accurate in classifying the following (where c1, c2 etc are class labels)

```
c1={3,4,5,5,7} 
c2={1,2,3,4,5,6} 
c3={1,4,5,7,8}
c4={3,5,6,9,10}
```

linear SVM gives me the following classes

```
c1={5,5,5,5,5,6,6} 
c2={1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4} 
c3={}
c4={7,7,8,9,10}
```

What I am looking to get is

```
 c1={1,1,2} 
 c2={3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5} 
 c3={6,6}
 c4={7,7,8,9,10}
```

Is there a better method to classify such datasets?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Do the lists represent input vectors or labels or ...?

Comment: The lists represents 4 classes and their members.

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression comes to mind.